# Program exepects to point to a *.exe that is running under Windows XP Mode

Tags: batch, redirection, windows-xp-mode

I have a program (Xilinx ISE 10.1) that I have to use [it is the last ISE which supported the Virtex-2, which one of our designs uses]. I'm using Active-HDL, which expects a *.exe file for ISE to point to, but I can't install ISE directly (because I'm running Windows 7 x86-64 and experiencing crashes).

I installed it under XP Mode, and it starts fine and it seems stable, but I can't get Active-HDL to point to it's executable location because it is actually being executed with this line (Taken from the shortcut to the XP Mode application):

%SystemRoot%\system32\rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\VMCPropertyHandler.dll,LaunchVMSal "Windows XP Mode" "||72dafd4e" "Project Navigator"

I *should* be able to modify the TCL script generated by Active-HDL to call this file, but honestly that's a diversion and I'd have to do some serious digging and I'm not sure if it would work (which makes it an unacceptable path to spend lots of time on - some rudimentary digging through the TCL files looks promising, but time consuming).

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small batch script which can run the command and use a [bat to exe converter](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) to create an executable which you can run.